# How to force a template parameter to be an enum or enum class?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I implemented the following class:

```
template<typename Enum>
class EnumDescription
{
    //TODO Force Enum to be an enum type

public:
    static std::string get( const Enum val );
};
```

This works as expected, but now I would like to constraint the Enum template parameter to be an enum/enum class only.

Comment: How about [`std::is_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on your flavor of C++.

**C++17**

The most easy to write way is a static assertion

```
template<typename Enum>
class EnumDescription
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<Enum>);

public:
    static std::string get( const Enum val );
};
```

**C++20**

You can specify an ad-hoc constraint on the template

```
template<typename Enum> requires std::is_enum_v<Enum>
class EnumDescription
{

public:
    static std::string get( const Enum val );
};
```

or, probably for the better, with a reusable concept

```
template<typename E>
concept EnumType = std::is_enum_v<E>;

template<EnumType Enum>
class EnumDescription
{

public:
    static std::string get( const Enum val );
};
```

Comment: And C++17's solution can be adapted for C++11/C++14 if needed.

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_enum<Enum>::value, "Not an enum");` to be precise